# Unable to load Win32 Native DLL file from C#.NET

Tags: c#, winapi, dll

I have a C# winapp. I call a native .dll file (created in C++ by myself) from the C# app, and it works fine.

But when I copy my application (.exe and .dll files) to another machine, I get an error that says:

*Unable to load DLL "c:\dllname.dll": The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)*

Here is the C# code:

```
class IsoMessageHelper
{
    public const string ISO8583_DLL = "c:\\Hc8583.dll";
    [DllImport(ISO8583_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool InitializationRq(...)
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Post your `<DllImport>` declaration from your C# code, please.

Comment: i edited the post, and wrote the C# dll import code too.

Comment: I notice your code still hardcodes the path to the DLL in the C:\ directory. As other answers have suggested, there's no reason to do this. An application will automatically load a DLL that is placed in the same directory as its executable. All you need is the file name.

Comment: the problem is not path and filename. it's .dll dependencies. my dll uses some functions from MSVCR100.dll that by default is not in windows\system32 folder. i copied tha mising dll , and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, chibacity already nailed that as your problem (you should accept his answer, by the way—click the hollow checkmark in the left-hand margin). I'm simply adding that it's not considered good practice to hardcode the path to DLLs in your application's source. The best place for them is your application's directory, and it will check there first if you omit the path specification. Glad to see that you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common issue when deploying .Net applications that have native dependencies, is that the native dlls may be missing dependencies themselves on the target machines e.g. the correct version of the C runtime.

Use a tool such a [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to analyze your native dll and determine if it has a missing dependency on the machine you have copied it too.

Comment: @user434186 Please note that you should vote up answers that are helpful and accept answers that solve your questions and problems.

Comment: File not found point to this as the answer. @user434186 Please do as @chibacity says and vote up good answers and accept the best answers from previous questions.

Comment: It's .dll dependencies. my dll uses some functions from MSVCR100.dll that by default is not in windows\system32 folder. i copied tha mising dll , and it worked fine. thanks.

Comment: @user434186 Great - now you should vote my answer up and accept it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to hard code any paths in the `DllImport` attribute parameter that specifies the name of the file. Then you should make usre the file is right besides the executable.

Something like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

Comment: i copied the .dll right beside the C# .exe file. even copied to 'C:\\' path and addressed it, but the problem exist!

Answer (score 1):

Move the DLL to the root. If that works, then look at your attribute to determine why. You haven't posted any code, so I can't give you any specific reason.

Comment: i copied the .dll right beside the C# .exe file. even copied to 'C:\\' path and addressed it, but the problem exist!