# Is it possible to directly use the Win32Native class from the Microsoft.Win32 namespace?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

Is there any way to directly use the Win32Native namespace?

I would like to directly call the method:

```
Win32Native.SendMessageTimeout(new IntPtr(0xffff), 0x1a, IntPtr.Zero, "Environment", 0, 0x3e8, IntPtr.Zero) == IntPtr.Zero;
```

as opposed to declaring it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult);
```

Is there any chance of that?

Comment: here is a good reference to look at from a previous StackOverFlowPost it makes great recommedations as well as some tools you can use incases where unmanaged .dll dependecys may not be present as well ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655294/unable-to-load-win32-native-dll-file-from-c-net

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm not having trouble importing the DLL though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean the `Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native` class. No, you cannot call it, it is internal. You could probably do something with reflection, but that would be even uglier.

Microsoft could change the API at any time; via a new Framework version, service pack, etc. Since it is internal, they have no obligation to support it even if they make a change that breaks your application if you were directly calling it.

In short: write the platform invoke yourself.

You should also look at http://pinvoke.net/. This site contains many platform invoke signatures already defined for you.

Comment: Are there any other classes that encapsulate the SendMessage API?  Seems odd that there aren't.